# Computing the rank funciton of the Well founded universe of sets

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion

**Definitions**: $(1)$ We define the $V_\alpha$ function by transfinite recursion as:

$V_0=\varnothing$; $V_{\alpha+1}=P(V_\alpha)$; Lim$(\lambda)\rightarrow V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}V_\alpha$

$(2)$ The rank function $\rho(x)$ is defined as the least $\tau$ such that $x\in V_{\tau+1}$

**Questions**: If $\rho(x)=\rho(y)=\alpha$ compute:

(i) $\rho(\{x,y\})$, (ii) $\rho(\langle x,y\rangle)$, (iii) $\rho((\alpha+\omega)\times y)$, (iv) $\rho(^{(\alpha+\omega)}y)$

**Answers*(attempt)**:

(i) $\rho(\{x\})=\rho(x)+1=\alpha+1$ and $\rho(\{y\})=\rho(y)+1=\alpha+1$, therefore $\rho(\{x,y\})=\alpha+1$

(ii) $\rho(\langle x,y\rangle)=\rho(\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\})$.

$\rho(\{\{x\}\})=\rho(x)+2=\alpha+2$ and $\rho(\{\{x,y\}\}=\rho(x,y)+2=\alpha+2$

Therefore $\rho(\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\})=\alpha+2$

(iii) Havn't been able to understand this question or the one after, dont really know how to deal with the limit case, I have found that $\rho(\omega)=\omega$, $\rho(\omega\times\omega)=\omega$ which I understand since they both look like limit cases, but then $\rho((\omega+1)\times(\omega+1))=\omega+3$ which I do not understand, but I can acknowledge that it is not like the limit case. Where does the $+3$ come from?

(iv)

Also if you could explain why $\rho(^xy)=\alpha+3$ it would help me a lot, or just a reference to material explaining it.

*Please verify if they are correct or if there are any mistakes

Comment: Your definition of *rank* is non-standard. The usual definition of the rank of $x$ is that it is the least $\tau$ such that $x\in V_{\tau+1}$ (equivalently, such that $x\subseteq V_\tau$). In (i), $\wp(x)$ is not $\{x\}$. What is true is that if $x,y\in V_\alpha$, then $\{x,y\}\in V_{\alpha+1}$. In (iii), $\alpha+\omega$ is an ordinal sum and is not equal to $\omega$ unless $\alpha$ is finite.

Comment: I’d rather not write up a full answer until I know whether you’re actually using this non-standard notion of rank or simply gave the wrong definition.

Comment: @Brian: I wouldn't say it's non-standard. I even argued in its favor on the site before. It is true that if you think about it long enough, wanting the rank function to be continuous and ordinals to have themselves as rank are sufficient arguments, but you can also argue that the rank of $x$ is the first time it *appears* in the universe, and appearing means being an object, rather than a collection of objects. It's really just the change of place for $\rho(x)=\sup\{\rho(y)\mid y\in x\}+1$ (as given in the question) or $\rho(x)=\sup\{\rho(y)+1\mid y\in x\}$ (as you and I would define it).

Comment: @Asaf: Your experience is certainly wider, but it’s the first time that I’ve seen it. And I realize that it doesn’t actually affect the answers here, just a detail in the working.

Comment: My mistake thanks for pointing it out, I have changed it to the correct definition

Comment: Ah yes, I realize my mistake in the power set of $x$. Will edit my work, if you come back in half an hour or so it will be fixed

Comment: @Dan: Sounds good. Leave me ping when it’s done, and I’ll take a look.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Improved my answer(hopefully), thanks for spending the time looking through my answers, I wish I could have given (iii) and (iv) a better go, but I feel very incompetent with the limit case.

Comment: Unsure what you mean by ping, I hope you get the message that I have finished my editing.

Comment: @Dan: That comment addressed to me is exactly what I meant by *ping*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (i) it would be better to tie the argument more directly to the definition of rank: $x,y\in V_{\alpha+1}$, so $\{x,y\}\subseteq V_{\alpha+1}$, and therefore $\{x,y\}\in V_{\alpha+2}$. However, this shows only that $\rho\big(\{x,y\}\big)\le\alpha+1$; to complete the argument, you need to show that $\{x,y\}\notin V_{\alpha+1}$. To see this, suppose that $\{x,y\}\in V_{\alpha+1}$. Then $\{x,y\}\in\wp(V_\alpha)$, so $\{x,y\}\subseteq V_\alpha$, and $x,y\in V_\alpha$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\rho(x)=\rho(y)=\alpha$.

In (ii) you don’t want to look at the sets $\big\{\{x\}\big\}$ and $\big\{\{x,y\}\big\}$: they never enter the picture. In fact, since $\{x\}=\{x,x\}$ you can use (i) to say that $\{x\}$ and $\{x,y\}$ both have rank $\alpha+1$, and then use (i) again to say that $\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}$ has rank $\alpha+2$.

For (iii) you want the fact that if $\beta$ is an ordinal, then $\rho(\beta)=\beta$; you can prove this by (transfinite) induction on $\beta$. Thus, $\rho(\alpha+\omega)=\alpha+\omega$. Elements of $(\alpha+\omega)\times y$ have the form $\langle\beta,z\rangle$, where $\beta\in\alpha+\omega$ and $z\in y$. For every such ordered pair we have $\rho(\beta)=\beta<\alpha+\omega$ and $\rho(z)<\alpha$. In (ii) you assumed that the components of the ordered pair had the same rank, but if you look more closely at the arguments for (i) and (ii), you’ll see that with a little work you can show in general that $\rho\big(\langle u,v\rangle\big)=\max\{\rho(u),\rho(v)\}+2$. Thus, for each $\langle\beta,z\rangle\in(\alpha+\omega)\times y$ we have

$$\rho\big(\langle\beta,z\rangle\big)=\max\{\beta,\alpha\}+2<\alpha+\omega\;.$$

It follows that $(\alpha+\omega)\times y\subseteq V_{\alpha+\omega}$, $(\alpha+\omega)\times y\in V_{\alpha+\omega+1}$, and hence $\rho\big((\alpha+\omega)\times y\big)\le\alpha+\omega$. I leave it to you to show that in fact $\rho\big((\alpha+\omega)\times y\big)=\alpha+\omega$.

To answer your question about $(\omega+1)\times(\omega+1)$, note that $\rho(\omega+1)=\omega+1$. Members of the Cartesian product are ordered pairs $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$, where $\alpha,\beta\le\omega$, and as above we have

$$\rho\big(\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\big)=\max\{\alpha,\beta\}+2\le\omega+2$$

for each $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\in(\omega+1)\times(\omega+1)$. Thus, $(\omega+1)\times(\omega+1)\subseteq V_{\omega+3}$, meaning that $(\omega+1)\times(\omega+1)\in V_{\omega+4}$, and hence that $\rho\big((\omega+1)\times(\omega+1)\big)\le\omega+3$. Here again I’ll leave you to verify that $(\omega+1)\times(\omega+1)\notin V_{\omega+3}$, so that the rank really is $\omega+3$ and not anything smaller. (What is $\rho\big(\langle\omega,\omega\rangle\big)$?)

For (iv) I’ll just address the question about $\rho({^xy})$ when $\rho(x)=\rho(y)=\alpha$. if $f\in{^xy}$, then $f\subseteq x\times y$, so the elements of $f$ are ordered pairs $\langle u,v\rangle$, where $u\in x$ and $v\in y$, so that $\rho(u),\rho(v)<\alpha$. In (ii) we essentially saw that $\rho\big(\langle u,v\rangle\big)=\max\{\rho(u),\rho(v)\}+2$.

If $\alpha=\beta+1$, $x\in V_{\alpha+1}\setminus V_{\alpha}=V_{\beta+2}\setminus V_{\beta+1}$, so $x\nsubseteq V_\beta$, and there is a $u\in x\setminus V_\beta$. Since $x\subseteq V_{\beta+1}$, this means that $\rho(u)=\beta$. Any $f\in{^xy}$ must contain a pair $\langle u,v\rangle$ for some $v\in y$, and $\rho\big(\langle u,v\rangle\big)=\beta+2=\alpha+1$. It’s not hard to check that this is the maximum rank of any member of $f$, and it follows that $\rho(f)=\alpha+2$ and hence that $\rho({^xy})=\alpha+3$.

If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, however, $\rho\big(\langle u,v\rangle\big)<\alpha$ whenever $\langle u,v\rangle\in x\times y$, so $\rho(f)\le\alpha$ for each $f\in{^xy}$. On the other hand, $x$ has elements of arbitrarily large rank less than $\alpha$, so each $f\in{^xy}$ has elements with arbitrarily large ranks less than $\alpha$, and therefore $\rho(f)=\alpha$. Thus, ${^xy}\subseteq V_{\alpha+1}$, and $\rho({^xy})\le\alpha+1$. Moreover, ${^xy}\nsubseteq V_\alpha$, so $\rho({^xy})=\alpha+1$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I could not have asked for a better answer, you have clearly spent so much time on making sure to give me a thorough answer, and you explained the exact problems I was having so well.

Comment: @Dan: You're very welcome; I'm glad that it helped.

Comment: Im unsure if this is a typo, but for part (iii) you say $\rho(\beta)=\beta<\alpha+\omega$ which is fine, but then $\rho(z)<\alpha$, is it supposed to be $\rho(z)<y$? If not, I am a little confused as to how it is $\alpha$. Surely $z\in y$ so $\rho(z)<y$

Comment: @Dan: $z\in y$, so $\rho(z)<\rho(y)=\alpha$.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that, so obvious, thanks

Comment: @Dan: You’re welcome. (It’s funny how often it’s the obvious things that get you! We’ve all been there.)